# Angular - ngFor and trackBy with async pipe

Tags: angular, performance, rxjs, ngfor

I want to use `trackBy` to improve performance for a long list. The data for this list should be immutable on change and is provided to the template via an async pipe. Altough I'm using the `trackBy` functionality, the whole list is rerendered everytime I emit a new value. This happens even though the objects inside the array stay the same with the same `id`.

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Observable<any>;

  trackBy(index, item) {
    return item.id;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const data = interval(100).pipe(mapTo([
      { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }
    ]))

    this.data = data.pipe(map(events => events.map(event => ({ ...event }))));
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data | async; trackBy: trackBy">{{d}}</div>
```

Additionally here is a [StackBlitz](https://angular-ttdujw.stackblitz.io/). The `div` tags are rerendered everytime a new value is send to the `ngFor`.

As I understand `trackBy` it should detect that the objects are the same (through the id property), altough the reference changed. Or am I missing something obviously?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the `trackBy` can be used to avoid rerendering components when the object does not change. While doing an `ngFor` on strings or number, it's obvious for Angular, but not on complex objects.

I made a little example to explain the different cases, starting from this Observable :

```
this.animals = interval(1000)
    .pipe(take(30),
    map(v => ({ id: v} as Animal)),
    scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []));
```

The results of this Observable :

```
 []
 [{id: 0}]
 [{id: 0}, {id: 1}]
 ...
```

I created a component displaying an input and having a random color everytime it renders, to make the render more obvious.

While using this trackBy fucntion, all the components renders everytime the list changes :

```
trackBy(index, item) {
    return Math.random();
}
```

While using this trackBy function, each component renders once only :

```
trackBy(index, item) {
    return item.id;
}
```

[Here you can find the running example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-57918301)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but unfortunately it doesn’t answer my question. Your explanation is what i thought how trackBy should work. I used the trackBy function in the same way you suggested in your answer, but in my case the items were still rerendered.

Comment: In your example, the items are not rerendring : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-57918301-2 Can you change your stackblitz in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is perfect! What I wonder is, if the object has additional properties that do change (ie. ids remain the same), will the template render the new values though?

Comment: @Climax Fork with additional properties : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-57918301-3 .

Comment: Thanks so much! I stumbled upon this fact too, but thanks for doing the effort!

Comment: Thanks man, your idea of checking trackby is awesome!